# Is ((f a) b) the same as (f a b) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, currying

```
map2_Maybe :: (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
map2_Maybe f Nothing _ = Nothing
map2_Maybe f (Just a) Nothing = Nothing
map2_Maybe f (Just a) (Just b) = Just ((f a) b)
-- Or: map2_Maybe f (Just a) mb = fmap (f a) mb

map2_Either :: (a -> b -> c) -> Either e a -> Either e b -> Either e c
map2_Either f (Left e) _ = Left e
map2_Either f (Right a) (Left e) = Left e
map2_Either f (Right a) (Right b) = Right (f a b)
-- Or: map2_Either f (Right a) eb = fmap (f a) eb
```

In these two examples, Is `((f a) b)` the same as `(f a b)` since every function in Haskell can only take one argument?

Comment: Yes it is. (This space intentionally left blank)

Comment: For the same reason, `(a -> b -> c)` and `(a -> (b -> c))` also mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Yes, both expressions result in exactly the same *abstract syntax tree*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haskell transposes (f a b) into ((f a) b). It's called currying. It does that to all functions by default but can be overridden.

```
 add = (+)
(add 1 2) -- becomes --  ((add 1) 2) -- upon execution.
```

Both return `3`. The result of a function is its value.

Curried functions are natural.

```
add1 = add 1
add1 2 -- also returns 3
```

Comment: Can you explain more about overriding currying?

Comment: that's not accurate. `uncurry` will return a function where the first two arguments are instead taken as a single tuple. Not 'all' parameters. Further it's not 'overriding' currying, it returns a new function with a different type. The returned function is still curried.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are exactly the same.